# casting operations on vnode (in NetBSD)

Tags: c, linux, unix, kernel, netbsd

In NetBSD system file usr/src/sys/sys/vnode.h defines structure of a vnode.
However, I see that sometime while performing an operation (lets say ufs_getattr) a vnode* is passed as a void* to the called operation.

Each such operation has its arguments structure. For Ex, ufs_getattr() the structure is as follows:

```
struct vop_getattr_args /* {
                struct vnode    *a_vp;
                struct vattr    *a_vap;
                kauth_cred_t    a_cred;
};
```

Generally, first line of these operations perform an assignment of vnode pointer, which was actually a void*, into a pointer of this argument type pointer. For Example, we do something like :

```
int
ufs_getattr(void *v)
{
        struct vop_getattr_args /* {
                struct vnode    *a_vp;
                struct vattr    *a_vap;
                kauth_cred_t    a_cred;
        } */ *ap = v;            //why this is okay to do ?
        struct vnode    *vp;
        struct inode    *ip;
        struct vattr    *vap;

        vp = ap->a_vp;           //wont this break ?
```

Extracted from usr/src/sys/ufs/ufs/ufs_vnops.c

Due to very little C programming knowledge I am unable to justify this mismatched assignment as the types do not really match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C, assigning a `void*` to a `T*` is legal (**not** so in C++). Therefore the code's perfectly valid.

Quoting "The C Programming Language 2<sup>nd</sup> Edition" by K&R:

> Any pointer to an object may be converted to type `void *` without loss of information. If the
>   result is converted back to the original pointer type, the original pointer is recovered. Unlike
>   the pointer-to-pointer conversions discussed in Par.A.6.6, which generally require an explicit
>   cast, pointers may be assigned to and from pointers of type `void *`, and may be compared
>   with them.

---

As an interesting sidenote, something about the history of `void*` (from the same book):

> This interpretation of `void *` pointers is new; previously, `char *` pointers played the role of
>   generic pointer. The ANSI standard specifically blesses the meeting of `void *` pointers with object
>   pointers in assignments and relationals, while requiring explicit casts for other pointer mixtures.